# Oracle APEX - Initializing an Interactive Grid Column Using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid in Apex that I'm trying to add a column that would have its values filled out using PL/SQL. I've added a column to the IG manually by right clicking on it in the page designer and clicking "Create Column". The issue I'm getting is I'm not seeing a way to have column initialized with the output of PL/SQL when I load the page. It seems like under the "Source" section after creating the column, there's only an option for using just SQL.

I've tried looking into dynamic actions for this, but I'm not seeing a way to set all the values in the column to a PL/SQL output when using the "Page Load" event. It seems like doing calculations on each row of a column is pretty straightforward using JavaScript, but I'm trying to port over numerous PL/SQL calculations into Apex so it would be preferable to do this without having to rewrite those scripts.

Is there a straightforward method to do this in Apex?

Comment: Is the PL/SQL you want to run a function (or can it be made into a function)?  If so, it sounds like you'd just want to go to the SQL query that populates the grid and add a column that makes the function call.

Comment: Another approach would be to use PL/SQL to load the data into a collection and query that in the IG. Really depends on the details of the requirements though.